# I think that's true but I don't know how I can prove it logically.

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Firstly I got it in my exam so I didn't know how I can prove that this sum cannot equal 2 or more.

By: $0\lt a \lt 1$

$\sum_{k=0}^n\ (a^k) \lt 2$

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^2\ (0.9^k)$

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: Your statement is not true as the example given by @ZenZen shows.  To make the connection, choose $a=0.9$ and $n=2$, then $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k = 1 + 0.9 +0.81 = 2.71 > 2$.  So it seems you have mis quoted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because it's not true. Take $a=\frac{2}{3}$, and $n=2$.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^na_k&=\sum_{k=0}^2 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k\\
&=1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{9}\\
&=\frac{19}{9}\\
&>2
\end{align*}

You tagged this with Cauchy Sequences; what you could do is notice that your sum is the $n^{th}$ partial sum for the sequence $a^k$. Since $0<a<1$, this sequence of partial sums is convergent, and therefore Cauchy. This implies the differences between terms gets small, so you could get $\left | \sum_{k=0}^na^k - \sum_{k=0}^ma^k\right|<2 $ for $n,m>N$ for sufficiently large $N$.

Comment: You right. I got it.